# Split string into array by regular expression without bracket

Tags: php, regex

My string  variable contains `"[100][200][300][400]"` data. 
This variable should be split it into array without brackets.

Currently I can split into `$matches` array  with regular expression, but bracket appear in array.

I have used current expression as bellow:

```
preg _match_all('/\[.*?\]/', $string , $matches)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not try this:

```
<?php
    $str = " [100][200][300][400] ";
    $str = explode("][", trim($str, "[] "));
    print_r($str);
    exit;
```

Comment: This is better solution than regex if you know that the characters you want to split on are not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

This code maybe can help

```
$str = "[100][200][300][400]";
$str = explode("][",trim($str,'\[\]'));
```

Results in:

`Array(
    [0] => 100 
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300 
    [3] => 400
  )`

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets to choose what part of the match you want to return.

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string , $matches)
```